# why use sync functions node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Everyone recommends using async (non-blocking) functions instead of sync functions in Node.js .

So whats the use of sync functions in node.js if they are not recommended?

For example : Why use `fs.readFileSync()` if `fs.readFile()` can do the same job without blocking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node It's not that they're not reccomended, it's just a use case

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863621/synchronous-read-or-write-on-nodejs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sync functions are useful, especially on startup, where you want to make sure that you have the result prior to executing any more code.

For example, you could load in a configuration file synchronously.  However, if you are trying to do a file read during a live request, you should use async functions so you don't block other user requests.

Comment: okay.....so from what I understand , sync functions not just block for that user but for others too . So a single blocking function can block the whole server from serving requests for that time?

Comment: That is correct.  Node is single-threaded, so while one thing is happening, nothing else can.  Using async functions let's the process go do other operations, then come back when it's finished.

Comment: What kind of config needs to be available sync when probably all your code using those configs are async?

Comment: For example, you may want to load a config file to get the port to run your server on.  You would get that in a sync call, since you won't be doing any concurrent work until your server is up.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes you want to execute code once you have finished reading or writing to a file. For example

```
function () {
    array.forEach(function(data) {
        fs.writeFile(data)
    });

    // do this after forEach has finished looping, not after files have finished being writen to
}
```

As apposed to:

```
function () {
    array.forEach(function(data) {
        fs.writeFileSync(data)
    });

    // do this after all files have been written to
}
```

Comment: This is an naive argument. Check the async module or any promise implementation

Comment: You would probably still want to use promise all still on this